# loading rails partial via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to load a partial via ajax. When I try to render the partial all I get is the render code printed to the screen.

JS

```
$("#filter_menu2 input:checkbox").click ->
  $.get "search", (data) ->
    $("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'new_shop/shop_search_results')).html_safe %>")
    return
```

controller

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html #search.html.erb
      format.js
    end
```

This is just getting printed the screen

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'new_shop/shop_search_results')).html_safe %>
```

Comment: Try to use `render_to_string` instead of `render`

Comment: mb you miss tabs after `$.get "search", (data) ->`

Comment: just corrected that. The tabs were correct in the code though.

Comment: Then that means you request is not correctly recognized as javascript format. For test it, put line with `debugger` to the each template. After make the request and check what template is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code in some `search.js.erb` and put `respond_to :js` at the top of your controller and at last return `format.js {render "search.js.erb"}`.

So, now `search.js.erb` contains this line

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'new_shop/shop_search_results')).html_safe %>")
```

Comment: what do I need to put in the search.js.erb? render the partial? $('#products').append('<%= j render('search') %>');

Comment: you have ti put this line `$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'new_shop/shop_search_results')).html_safe %>")`